# Jquery checkbox on select add a name attribute and increment on more than one selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Ok,i am building a fantansy football game using codeigniter , Grocery CRUD and Jquery. I have a view where user select 15 players from checkboxes where i will use the name attribute to select GK1,GK2,DEF1,DEF2,DEF3,DEF4,DEF5,MID1,MID2,MID3,MID4,MID5,FWD1,FWD2 and FWD3 and pass their value to the controller. My question is , how do i create  a javascript Jquery Code for maybe Midfielders (MID) in such a way that when a user click the first Midfielder the javascript  append input name="MID1"  and on checking another box  it becomes input name="MID2" without changing the name for MID1. So far i the javascript is working but when i click another player the name value changes in all players also if i deselect the name player for that particular player doesnt remove. Here is my JS..

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".gk").change(function() {
            var number=$('[class="gk"]:checked').length;
            if(this.checked) {


                $(".gk").each(function() {
                    $(".gk").attr('name',"GK"+number);
                });

            } else {
                $('.gk').attr('name', number);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and here is my view

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="gk"  value="<?=$row->playerID ?>" > <?= $row->playerID?> </input>
```

Comment: $(".gk").each(function() {
                    $(".gk").attr('name',"GK"+number);
                }); — this parses all .gk players and changes the name of each one of them.

Comment: @Bonatoc,how can i change individual element,please help...

Comment: What is number variable suppose to be?, right now it is the amount of checked gk's?, also you are declaring number inside the if clause and then also use it in the else clause, you probably want to declare number ouside of the if-statement.

Comment: @AdrianForsius,Thanks for pinpointing on the declaration inside if,i have put it outside if and that problem is solved now when i deselect , the number changes. you are right,the number account for the number of checked goalkeepers which will help me to have a name for GK1 and GK2 and insert them to the database. the only challenge right now is having different names on selection,eg only name for GK1 when only one is selected and GK1 and GK2 when both checkboxes are selected.any help i would appreciate,thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issue of all players having their name changed, the culprit may be '.each()'. Isn't it supposed to be  more like :

```
$(".gk").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var number=$('[class="gk"]:checked').length;

            // $(".gk").each(function() {
                $(this).attr('name',"GK"+number);
            // });
```

Comment: i tried that and still i am getting the same values.any more suggestion would appreciate :-)

Comment: Well of course, because 'this' refers to all elements with class ".gk". You need to write an HTML attribute (id, name, ref...) in which you will store some unique identifier, so you know which player has been clicked. But we're not gonna code for you... You should pause for a little while and think about the logic of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you have a problem when you deselect the players, since you are only running that piece of code that updates the name when the $(".gk") is checked... also, in order to add a different number to each one, you'll have to increment an index value, for example, and add it to the name, not the variable number, which will be the size of the selected elements... On top of this, the last variable "number" should be outside of the "if" otherwise you won't see it in the else...

Check this, see if it helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gk").change(function() {
        var checked=$('[class="gk"]:checked').length;
        alert("You have "+checked+" Gks checked")
        var index = 1;
        $(".gk").each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                $(this).attr('name',"GK"+index);
                alert("Getting GK "+index)
                alert("this GK name is "+$(this).attr('name') 
                index++;
            }    
            else {
                $('.gk').attr('name',"");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xn3P9/5/

Once you update the name it won't show on the page inspector.

You final solution should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gk").change(function() {
        var index = 1;
        $(".gk").each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                $(this).attr('name',"GK"+index);
                index++;
            }    
            else {
                 $('.gk').attr('name',"");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the alerts seems to display what i wanted but unfortunately the name has no value in it.i tried inspecting it and it produces output like this <input type="checkbox" class="gk" value="3" name=""> . Any suggestion on whats wrong ? Thanks again for helping out :-)

Comment: getting  <input type="checkbox" class="gk" value="3" name="GK1">  and  <input type="checkbox" class="gk" value="3" name="GK2"> is all i want to accomplish...

Comment: I updated the code, there was a small error.. You had $(".gk").attr instead of $(this).attr and I didn't notice.. Now, regarding the inspector, once you update the attribute name, it won't show on the page inspector but it will be updated, as you can check on the alert message. The fiddle is also updated.Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help,your code is right but i have realize $(this).attr('name',"GK"+index); does not work that is why the name is empty in my form cause i tried it with static value and yet it didnt work. Any suggestion...i am stil figuring a way out to output the name attribute...appreciate a lot for your support , lets fix this small issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

I still have a hard time understanding what you are looking for but maybe it is something similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gk").change(function() {
        $(".gk:checked").each(function(index, gk) {
            //Will give each selected GK a unique name
            $(".gk:checked").attr("name", "GK"+index);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: that one produces <input type="checkbox" class="gk" value="4" name="GK0GK1GK2GK3GK4GK5"> ... all i want to accomplish is that i get different input names for players so as later i could pass them to controller using the POST method and insert them to my database that has columns for 15 selected players. so imagine i have 28 goalkeepers from 14 clubs and  a fantansy team user has to select only 2 goalkepeers which means the 2 goalkeepers selected will have a input name of GK1 and GK2 and i will use that to create a fantansy team for a specific user.Hope now you understood, any advise wil aprct.

Comment: I edited my code this will produce unique names for each selected input field: <input name="GK1" />, <input name="GK2" /> etc